# Why did Mr White text Vesper's phone at the end of Casino Royale?

Tags: plot-explanation, casino-royale

I just watched *Casino Royale* trying to understand every plot move.

At the end of the movie when Bond is on his ship, he picks up Vesper's phone and receives a message saying "For James........Mr. White". Mr. White knows Vesper is dead but he does not know Bond has her phone.

1. Why would Mr. White send a message to a dead person?
2. What is the purpose of this message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You misunderstand...the message wasn't from Mr White, it was a message from Vesper to Bond giving him a clue as to who was involved and a number he could trace.

[image]

The [screenplay](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Casino-Royale.pdf) indicates much the same

> Then he picks up her cell phone, hits a button, checks the address book... and understands why she left the cell phone, and is overcome with emotion.

Comment: Thank you, but the message date time is the the actual phone time. Vesper is dead, so who sent it ?

Comment: You're looking at this too hard. I'm not sure how you know what the actual time is in the movie but it's clear that the message is intended to be from Vesper.